# How to find out why Angular app running on IIS does not allow 'Open link in new tab' for a route / url?

Tags: angular, iis

This works on angular development server, but on IIS (10.0) I get

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

on Chrome. When I click the link it works without any problem. With angular development server I use proxy.conf.json to enable API-calls. In IIS these are defined as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*pn/api/.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://b-XXX:19100/{C:3}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*api/.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://([^/]+).*(api/.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://b-ZZZ:18221/{C:3}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".cmap" mimeType="text/plain" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdm" mimeType="text/plain" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdt" mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>YYY App</title>
  <base href="/yyyapp/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.0a90b702423cc0234e73.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.a73720f7fce1093697ef.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.9142a59cca85c6bb7aa5.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.fc2905abff461388a63e.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **web.config** file in the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for answer! now the links can be opened but it says IIS Windows Server in the title and the content is not what is is supposed to be. instead it is blue background with nothing else except IIS link on top https://www.iis.net/?utm_medium=iis-deployment. the url in address-bar is correct.

Comment: Please show the `<base href>` from index.html. Basically path in`<base href>` and url in `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />` should be same

Comment: I edit the question to contain other missing information as well. I have reverse proxy defined which might also affect this.